# Visualize Data That Dynamically Updates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

TLDR: How can I create a bar chart that updates the x-axis daily? The end goal is to have a chart that shows a side by side comparison of goal completions performance for each source of traffic. Here is a couple of examples of what it looks currently. 
[image]
[image]

I have used the google analytics add on for google sheets to create a workbook that provides an analysis of our event tracking & goal completions.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

I am having trouble getting the daily, weekly, & monthly reports by source to visualize properly.  I have been able to figure out the overview reports and that should provide enough context to understand what I'm trying to do with the "by source" reports. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YvdVXbH5biaW2qY4pPi_g1AkNeJ0Dy9rcE2yQzCx2Xc/edit?usp=sharing

I have removed the report configuration tab but this workbook runs daily and compares to previous day, week, & month. Therefore, the source/mediums are constantly updating and I don't know how to visualize them properly because of the dynamic changes that create discrepancies in the source/mediums over time.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: whats the question exactly?

Comment: @player0 I need to visualize the "by source" bar charts properly.  See my edits above.   Thanks!